# _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, "v"

Tags: machine-learning, flask, deployment, pickle, git-lfs

recently faced this error during the deployment of my project on **netify app**

```
6:39:50 PM: added 329 packages, and audited 330 packages in 4s
6:39:50 PM: 107 packages are looking for funding
6:39:50 PM:   run `npm fund` for details
6:39:50 PM: 1 moderate severity vulnerability
6:39:50 PM: To address all issues, run:
6:39:50 PM:   npm audit fix
6:39:50 PM: Run `npm audit` for details.
6:39:50 PM: > movie@0.0.0 build
6:39:50 PM: > vite build
6:39:50 PM: vite v5.0.2 building for production...
6:39:50 PM: transforming...
6:39:52 PM: ✓ 52 modules transformed.
6:39:52 PM: rendering chunks...
6:39:52 PM: computing gzip size...
6:39:52 PM: dist/index.html                   0.53 kB │ gzip:  0.33 kB
6:39:52 PM: dist/assets/back-dm-GU_Ur.jpg   514.14 kB
6:39:52 PM: dist/assets/index-CLk4a_k1.css   12.90 kB │ gzip:  3.41 kB
6:39:52 PM: dist/assets/index-3jaT-T7k.js   209.08 kB │ gzip: 68.51 kB
6:39:52 PM: ✓ built in 1.60s
6:39:52 PM: loading data -------------------
6:39:52 PM: Traceback (most recent call last):
6:39:52 PM:   File "app.py", line 12, in <module>
6:39:52 PM:     movies = load_data.load_movies()
6:39:52 PM:   File "/opt/build/repo/utils/load_data.py", line 7, in load_movies
6:39:52 PM:     return pkl.load(open("./data/movies.pkl","rb"))
6:39:52 PM: _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, "v".
6:39:52 PM: ​
6:39:52 PM: "build.command" failed                                        
6:39:52 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
6:39:52 PM: ​
6:39:52 PM:   Error message
6:39:52 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: cd client && npm install && npm run build && cd .. && python app.py (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
6:39:52 PM: ​
6:39:52 PM:   Error location
6:39:52 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
6:39:52 PM:   cd client && npm install && npm run build && cd .. && python app.py
6:39:52 PM: ​
6:39:52 PM:   Resolved config
6:39:52 PM:   build:
6:39:52 PM:     base: /opt/build/repo
6:39:52 PM:     command: cd client && npm install && npm run build && cd .. && python app.py
6:39:52 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
6:39:52 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo
6:39:52 PM:     publishOrigin: default
6:39:53 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
6:39:53 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
6:39:53 PM: Finished processing build request in 24.831s
6:39:53 PM: Failed during stage "building site": Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
```

**build command**
`pip install -r requirements.txt ; cd client ; npm install ; npm run build ; cd .. ; python app.py`

**Main goal**
using pkl model in backend (flask) to predict similar movies to user on frontend (react)
I have deployed pkl files on github using git lfs

**Main goal**
using pkl model in backend (flask) to predict similar movies to user on frontend (react)
I have deployed pkl files on github using git lfs